# Flask - Updating Forms Without Reload

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm trying to make my app as responsive as possible so I don't want my page reloaded every time when a POST request is made. I have a dynamically generated form and input fields like this

```
<div class="dropdown-objects">
    <button class="dropbtn-objects">Objects</button>
        <div class="dropdown-objects-content">
            {% for name in session['objects'].keys() %}
            <a href="#">{{ name }}</a>
            <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="submission-form">
                <input type="number" name="{{ name }}" value="{{ session['objects'][name]['quantity'] }}" min="1" onblur="this.form.submit()">
            </form>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
</div>
```

Data is read from session and rendered to template. When onblur is triggered in those forms, values are submitted and session is updated. This is how I handle requests.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    if request.method == 'GET':

            # some code here
            ...
            return render_template('index.html')

    elif request.method == 'POST':

        for submitted_key, submitted_value in list(request.form.items()):

            if submitted_key in session['objects'].keys():
                session['objects'][submitted_key]['quantity'] = submitted_value
            elif submitted_key in session['settings'].keys():
                session['settings'][submitted_key] = submitted_value

        return render_template('index.html')
```

The page reloads every time when onblur is triggered. Is it possible to update session with an async request without using JavaScript and jQuery, so doesn't reload?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. Your code submits the form when the onblur event is triggered. Submitting a form directly results in a page reload.

To prevent page reload, you need to use Ajax to execute the form submission i.e. you need to override the form submit event and then use Ajax to submit the form. A sample code (taken from - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery) is shown below

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
    var formData = {
      name: $("#name").val(),
      email: $("#email").val(),
      superheroAlias: $("#superheroAlias").val(),
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "process.php",
      data: formData,
      dataType: "json",
      encode: true,
    }).done(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });

    event.preventDefault(); // this prevents the normal form submit i.e. the one that causes page reload
  });
```

Comment: I'm assuming there is no way to do it with Flask.